# Angle trisection existence

Tags: geometry

We know that most angles cannot be trisected using a compass and straightedge. For the ones that can't be trisected, the trisection still exists geometrically, but it is impossible to recreate using a compass and straightedge? So it is not that the trisection doesn't exist geometrically but that we can't produce it using geometrical tools?

Comment: "Yes" to your question. It's analogous to $\sqrt{2}$ being impossible to create using integers and the four arithmetic operations, or $\frac{1}{2}$ being impossible to create using integers and the arithmetic operations excluding division, or being impossible to create the antiderivative of $e^{-{x}^{2}}$ using precalculus functions, or being impossible to create the trig. functions using polynomials and the four arithmetic operations and composition of functions, or being impossible to create a nonzero number using only $0$ and the arithmetic operations excluding division, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's just about the tools. Abstractly, any angle can be trisected. For example, a famous result about trisected angles is [Morley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley's_trisector_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

In a word, "yes". For example, an [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral) (together with a straightedge and compass) can be used to subdivide an angle into an arbitrary finite number of pieces.

Incidentally, an arbitrary angle can also be trisected *in the limit after infinitely many steps* using only a straightedge and compass.

Answer (score 0):

You can trisect an angle using neusis see http://www.britannica.com/topic/Trisecting-the-Angle-Archimedes-Method-724632